# How can I configure a ip range in CentOS7?

Tags: centos

In the CentOS6, we can easily config a ip range(such as:`192.168.1.10-192.168.1.254`) to a NIC,
but how can we config a ip range in the CentOS7?

I can not use the method in the CentOS6, how to do with in CentOS7?

I can use below method to configure multi ip, but if I have 200 ip, how to do with that?

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="933cdc9b-b383-4ddd-b219-5a72c69c9cf0"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="08:00:27:3F:AB:68"
IPADDR0="192.168.1.150"
IPADDR1="192.168.1.151"
IPADDR2="192.168.1.152"
PREFIX0="24"
GATEWAY0="192.168.1.1"
DNS1="192.168.1.1"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set the ip range like CentOS6, in CentOS7 you can write script to archive that:

```
for I in {5..250}
> do nmcli con mod eth33554960 -ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.${I}/24
> nmcli con mod eth33554960 +ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.${I}/24
> done
```

Answer (score 5):

#### You have to use a range file

1. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` and make sure that `NM_CONTROLLED` is set to `NO` (preventing the network manager to control the interface is required to use range files)
2. Create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3-range`:

   ```
   IPADDR_START=192.168.1.10
   IPADDR_END=192.168.1.254
   PREFIX=24
   CLONENUM_START=0
   ```
3. run `systemctl restart network` and the changes should be effective.

If you wanted to configure multiple ranges you could create other file (`ifcfg-enp3s0-range0`, `ifcfg-enp3s0-range1`, ...)

Comment: This method works for CentOS6 but not CentOS7.

Comment: I don't have a centos 7 runing at the moment but I really think it works last time I tried. You made sure to set `NM_CONTROLLED=NO` ?

Comment: You need to set NM_CONTROLLED="no" even if you do not use network manager or have it installed.

Comment: I have the latest Centos 7 and this worked for me.  The key is keeping NM out of the way for the device you are going to apply the range to.